# Problema para gerar números inteiros no gráfico Chartist.JS

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4, gráfico

Estou usando um plugin chamado `chartist.js` ele funciona bem o problema está sendo  os números laterais eu estou colocando de 1 a 5 o ideal seria ficar assim `1 2 3 4 5` porem ele está gerando assim `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5` e assim por diante eu não consigo deixar os números inteiros e fora que o gráfico fica gigante de atura segue meu código e uma screenchot de como deveria ficar e de como está ficando

HTML:

```
<div class="box-os">
            <div class="box-title">
              <h1 class="title">Informações gerais da O.S</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="box-info-os">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 align-self-center">
                      <div class="p-4">
                        <i class="material-icons">build</i>
                        <h1 class="number">7.516<br><span>Ordem de serviços abertas</span></h1>
                        <p class="card-text">Cerca de <span>7.250 clientes</span> estão satisfeitos com os serviços prestados </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-center">
                      <div class="ct-chart-os ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ct-series-a .ct-line {
                stroke: $gray-medium;
                stroke-width: 4px;
              }

              .ct-series-b .ct-line {
                stroke: $blue-1;
                stroke-width: 4px;
              }

              .ct-series-b .ct-bar, .ct-series-b .ct-line, .ct-series-b .ct-point, .ct-series-b .ct-slice-donut{
                stroke: $blue-1;
              }

              .ct-series-b .ct-area, .ct-series-b .ct-slice-donut-solid, .ct-series-b .ct-slice-pie{
                fill: $blue-1;
              }

              .ct-label{
                fill: $gray-light;
                color: $gray-light;
              }

              .ct-grid {
                stroke: $gray-light;
                stroke-width: 1px;
                stroke-dasharray: 2px;
            }
```

JS:

```
 var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-os', {
  labels: ['Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
  series: [{
    name: 'series-1',
    data: [1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'series-2',
    data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1]
  }]
}, {
  fullWidth: true,
  high: 5,
  onlyInteger: true,
  chartPadding: 30,
  low: 0,

  axisX: {
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true,
  },

  axisY: {
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true,
    offset: 0,
    onlyInteger: true,
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
      return (value / 1) + 'k';
    }
  },

  series: {
    'series-1': {
      lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple(),
      showPoint: false,
      showArea: false
    },
    'series-2': {
      lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple(),
      showPoint: true,
      showArea: false

    }
  },
  height: '300px' 
}, [
]);
```

Está ficando assim apos inserir altura fixa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e é assim que tem que ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara segundo a documentação para controlar se é inteiro o não deveria usar o `onlyInteger` https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html

```
// Can be set to true or false. If set to true, the scale will be generated with whole numbers only.
onlyInteger: true,
```

Só que vc tem que usar no eixo que vc escolher X ou Y, e o mesmo vale para a linha se vc quer remover no X ou Y, no seu caso ficaria assim

```
  axisX: { 
    showGrid: false //remove linhas do grid no eixo X
  },
  axisY: {
    onlyInteger: true //seta só números inteiros no Y
  }
```

O height vc pode controlar até pelo CSS usando por exemplo `.ct-chart { height: 300px; }` ou como fiz abaixo, dentro dos *options*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o exemplo da imagem acima

```js
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  series: [
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 1, 8],
  ]
}, {
  high: 8,
  low: 0,
  showArea: false,
  showLine: true,
  showPoint: false,
  onlyInteger: false,
  fullWidth: true,
  axisX: {
    showGrid: false
  },
  axisY: {
    onlyInteger: true,
  },
width: '300px', //largura se quiser...
  height: '200px' //altura se quiser
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.3/chartist.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.3/chartist.min.js"></script>

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

Comment: maravilha agora sabe porque o grafico fica gigante desse jeito da imagem ? se eu colocar um offset que e uma propriedade do proprio plugin resolve isso porem fica uma espaço vazio como se tivesse uma div vazia com tamanho fixo entende ?

Comment: @FelipeHenrique reveja o código, execute novamente, acabei de editar o script, falando como controla o height. São as duas últimas propriedades alo, deixei o comment do lado. Acredito que vc não vai precisar mais desse offset...

Comment: @hugocls então eu editei a pergunta para você ver como ficou o resultado funcionou mas fica um espaço vazio  eu alterei o script e coloquei na pergunta para você ver como está ficando tem um print

Comment: @FelipeHenrique conferiu pelo DevTools se o gráfico ficou com 300px mesmo? Acho que o seu problema pode ser nesse lado http://prntscr.com/p4fh6m e não no lado do gráfico...

Comment: @hudocls então isso é apenas um card eu fiz uma alteração no código para vc ver o html eu tbm coloquei um print do console mostrando que o grafico tem 300px mesmo

Comment: @FelipeHenrique só com o print não consigo te ajudar, coloca um height fixo no card-body  pra ver se ajuda. Tipo coloca height 320 no card